# Creating a New ArrayList for Every Object Instantiated

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class, `Employee`, as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employee extends Person 
{
    int salary;
    ArrayList<Sales> sales = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee(String name, int phoneNumber, String address, 
                    int salary, ArrayList<Sales> sales)
    {
        super(name, phoneNumber, address);
        this.salary = salary;
        this.sales = sales; 
    }
}
```

Now, for every `Employee` I also have to store an `ArrayList` of sales that each `Employee` makes. My approach to this was to make a `Sales` class and add `ArrayList<Sales> sales = new ArrayList<>();` to the `Employee` constructor. Am I headed in the right direction, or am I completely off?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you seem to be doing two things : passing an ArrayList into Employee constructor assigning it directly to the sales AND also creating a new ArrayList<Sales> - this is definitely redundant.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using the `List` interface for your field to promote loose coupling! Secondly, `List` contains the `addAll` method which you should use to copy the list's elements:

```
// ...
private int salary;
private List<Sales> sales = new ArrayList<>();

public Employee(String name, int phoneNumber, String address, int salary, List<Sales> sales) {
    super(name, phoneNumber, address);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.sales.addAll(sales);
}
```

Comment: +1 for defensive programing, -1 for using List, if you have a Method getList it should return the interface List but you should take advantage of your implementation where you could.

Comment: Ok, then I'd replace it with `Collection` instead of `List` to be even more generic. You can change your internal field type later if you need access to anything `ArrayList` or `HashSet` or whatever implements later on.

Comment: I recommand not doing that, List in most cases is the better way to go, because a Set is also a Collection but to know if you get unique "list" or not is something to consider, thats why i would say: context dependent but in most cases, use List or Set

Comment: It really depends on the use of the collection. For instance, when I make a class that can add and remove `EventListener`s, I tend to use a `Set` instead of `List` (and a `CopyOnWriteArraySet` at that) due to the usual convention that listeners will be notified in an undefined order when an event is fired.

Comment: As long as your EventListener override hashCode() and equals() you are fine.